# SQL: grouping 2 tables as 1 with join, union, and then?

Tags: sql, select, join, union

I have 5 tables:

customers
id - name

p_orders
id - id_customer - code - date

p_items
id - id_order - description - price

and h_orders and h_items, that are exactly the copy of p_orders and p_items.

When the p_ tables reach a big amount of rows, i move the oldest to the h_ tables.. they due as history.

So, my problem is: **how to retrieve the data from both the p_ tables and h_ considering them as one unique table**?

For example, i want to retrieve the number of orders for each customer, and the total price (**of all the customer's orders**), and i use that query:

```
SELECT
    customer.id,
    customer.name,
    count(DISTINCT p_orders.id) AS num_orders,
    sum(p_items.price) AS total_money
FROM
    customer
    INNER JOIN p_orders ON p_orders.id_customer = customer.id
    INNER JOIN p_items ON p_items.id_order = p_orders.id
GROUP BY
    customer.id,
    customer.name,
    p_orders.id_customer
ORDER BY
    customer.id
```

it works just for one 'set' of tables (p_ or h_)..but i want them both.

I've tryed to use an UNION:

```
(
    SELECT
        customer.id,
        customer.name,
        count(DISTINCT p_orders.id) AS num_orders,
        sum(p_items.price) AS total_money
    FROM
        customer
        INNER JOIN p_orders ON p_orders.id_customer = customer.id
        INNER JOIN p_items ON p_items.id_order = p_orders.id
    GROUP BY
        customer.id,
        customer.name,
        p_orders.id_customer
)
UNION
(
    SELECT
        customer.id,
        customer.name,
        count(DISTINCT h_orders.id) AS num_orders,
        sum(h_items.price) AS total_money
    FROM
        customer
        INNER JOIN h_orders ON h_orders.id_customer = customer.id
        INNER JOIN h_items ON h_items.id_order = h_orders.id
    GROUP BY
        customer.id,
        customer.name,
        h_orders.id_customer
)
ORDER BY id ASC
```

This one works, but if a customer have orders both in the p_ tables and in the h_ tables, i'll have 2 rows for that customer with 2 different num_orders and total_money (respectively coming from p_ tables and h_ tables)

I've tryed to add a GROUP BY id outside the union:

```
(
    --SELECT 2
)
UNION
(
    --SELECT 1
)
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id ASC
```

but the query fail with *ERROR:  syntax error at or near "GROUP" at character 948*, seem like GROUP BY cannot be used in that way.

Any suggestion?

**EDIT:**

For uriDium, yes, all the tables have the id column as primary key, and the referred fields (aka p_orders.id_customer) are foreign keys too.
Here the test db structure dump (i added some indexes and foreign keys after the table creation, but i dont think that this mean something):

```
CREATE TABLE customer (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    name character(50)
);
CREATE TABLE p_orders (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    id_customer integer NOT NULL,
    date date DEFAULT now(),
    code character(5)
);
CREATE TABLE p_items (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    id_order integer NOT NULL,
    descr character(250),
    price money
);
CREATE TABLE h_orders (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    id_customer integer NOT NULL,
    date date,
    code character(5)
);
CREATE TABLE h_items (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    id_order integer NOT NULL,
    descr character(250),
    price money
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX id_h_orders ON h_orders USING btree (id);
CREATE INDEX id_h_o_c ON h_orders USING btree (id_customer);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX id_items_h ON h_items USING btree (id);
CREATE INDEX id_ordinr_dsve ON h_items USING btree (id_order);

ALTER TABLE ONLY customer
    ADD CONSTRAINT customer_pkey  (id);
ALTER TABLE ONLY p_orders
    ADD CONSTRAINT p_orders_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE ONLY p_items
    ADD CONSTRAINT p_items_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE ONLY stats
    ADD CONSTRAINT stats_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE ONLY p_orders
    ADD CONSTRAINT "$1" FOREIGN KEY (id_customer) REFERENCES customer(id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE ONLY p_items
    ADD CONSTRAINT "$1" FOREIGN KEY (id_order) REFERENCES p_orders(id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE ONLY h_orders
    ADD CONSTRAINT "$1" FOREIGN KEY (id_customer) REFERENCES customer(id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE ONLY h_items
    ADD CONSTRAINT "$1" FOREIGN KEY (id_order) REFERENCES h_orders(id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should probably create views over the two tables:

```
CREATE VIEW All_Orders
AS
     SELECT
          id,
          id_customer,
          code,
          date,
          'H' AS order_type
     FROM
          h_orders
     UNION ALL
     SELECT
          id,
          id_customer,
          code,
          date,
          'P' AS order_type
     FROM
          p_orders

CREATE VIEW All_Order_Items  -- A table name of "items" is pretty bad in my opinion
AS
     SELECT
          id,
          id_order,
          description,
          price,
          'H' AS order_item_type
     FROM
          h_items
     UNION ALL
     SELECT
          id,
          id_order,
          description,
          price,
          'P' AS order_item_type
     FROM
          p_items
```

Now you can just join to those views. I included the types (P & H) so that you know what the "id" column now refers to. If the ids in your two tables ("h" and "p" can have duplicates then you will have to join the Orders table right in the All_Order_Items view. Otherwise you will have a lot of trouble joining between the two views. Hopefully your id columns are intelligently designed and not just auto-incrmenting or identity columns.

Comment: No, when i move the data from p_* to h_* i keep the same values of the columns, even the id - and in both tables is defined as unique primary key, the only difference is that in the h_* table there is no the sequence for auto increment the id value on every insert

Comment: "Hopefully your id columns are intelligently designed and not just auto-incrmenting or identity columns." Identity ids are an intelligent way to design in most  business applications.

Comment: What do you exactly mean, HLGEM?
You think i do a wrong (or inefficent) use of the ids? please explain.. im here to learn!

Comment: @DaNieL - Since you're keeping the ID values, you should be in good shape

Comment: It sounds like the id scheme is "correctly" designed: auto-increment in p*, then preserved when moving to h*.

Read "correctly", of course, as "how I'd do it"... ;)

Comment: I must keep the original id from p_*, becose there are other tables using the orders and items data :)

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
SELECT tbl.ID, 
       tbl.Name, 
       sum(tbl.num_orders) num_orders, 
       sum(tbl.total_money) total_money
FROM (    
      SELECT customer.id, 
             customer.name,        
             count(DISTINCT p_orders.id) AS num_orders,        
             sum(p_items.price) AS total_money    
      FROM customer        
            INNER JOIN p_orders 
                ON p_orders.id_customer = customer.id        
            INNER JOIN p_items 
                ON p_items.id_order = p_orders.id    
      GROUP BY customer.id, customer.name, p_orders.id_customer

      UNION

      SELECT customer.id, 
             customer.name,        
             count(DISTINCT h_orders.id) AS num_orders,
             sum(h_items.price) AS total_money    
      FROM  customer        
             INNER JOIN h_orders 
                 ON h_orders.id_customer = customer.id
             INNER JOIN h_items 
                 ON h_items.id_order = h_orders.id    
      GROUP BY customer.id, customer.name, h_orders.id_customer
    ) tbl
 GROUB BY tbl.id, tbl.name
 ORDER BY tbl.id ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a view with the union of the two queries but without the aggregate functions. USe Union All as the same record is not in both tables and you don't need the server to waste time looking to see that.You will probaly have other times you want to access both tables in a query.

Then write your query using the view.

view code would be something like (you may want other fields for other purposes as well:

```
Create view customerOrders
AS
SELECT      customer.id as CustomerID,  customer.name, p_orders.id as OrderID,  p_items.price  as price
FROM        customer        
INNER JOIN  p_orders ON p_orders.id_customer = customer.id        
INNER JOIN  p_items ON p_items.id_order = p_orders.id
union all
SELECT      customer.id,  customer.name,  h_orders.id as id, H_items.price           
FROM        customer        
INNER JOIN  h_orders ON h_orders.id_customer = customer.id        
INNER JOIN  h_items ON h_items.id_order = h_orders.id
```

then the call for your query would be something like (none of this is tested may need adjustment)

```
SELECT    CustomerID,    customer.name,    count(DISTINCT OrderID) AS num_orders,    
sum(price) AS total_money
FROM    customerOrders
GROUP BY     CustomerID,    customer.name
ORDER BY    CustomerID
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know SQL Server should automatically eliminating duplicates. Using UNION ALL will include duplicates. I would imagine that SQL Server would use the primary keys as a means of working out what is a duplicate. Are the primary keys on these tables made up of the same datatype and is ID 1 in your p table also ID 1 in your h table?

Comment: I believe that with a union, all fields are considered during duplicate elimination - not just the keys.

Comment: Yes - Edited with the test database tructure

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do what you are looking at would be to create views (say "a_orders" and "a_items").  The views would just be defined like:

```
SELECT * FROM p_orders
UNION
SELECT * FROM h_orders
```

If you delete rows from a_orders as you insert them to h_orders (so a given order would not be in both tables) it would be quite a bit more efficient to use UNION ALL instead of UNION.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the replies, guys..

Both the 'views way' and the 'subquery way' by Jimmie R. Houts works perfectly, maybe the views are just more convenient to use.. and them both should take the same time (or not?)

So i'll mark as best answer the first one about the views.

Anyway, if i can, may i ask you if the structure and indexes i used are a good or could be optimized?